# Apacheがphpをディレクトリの違いで認識しない

Tags: php, centos, apache

apache2.2
php5.3.29
centos7
をソースよりインストールしました。
httpd.confに以下の設定をしました。

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source.phps
```

/var/www/index.phpに

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

を記述しアクセスするとphpの情報がブラウザに表示されます。

しかし、var/www/xxx/index.phpに

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

を記述すると開く／ダウンロードの選択を迫られます。

httpd.confに追加で設定等がありますでしょうか。
ご指摘／アドバイスよろしくお願い致します。

以下httpd.confの全文

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source.phps

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
MultiViews
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""     combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: 親側のディレクティブがどうなっているのかわからないので,可能ならhttpd.confをすべて貼り付けると良いと思います.なお,拡張子でのphp実行はユーザがfoo.php.pngのようなファイルを投稿するとphpが実行されてしまうためきちんとファイルでマッチしないと脆弱性が生じる可能性があります.

Comment: `Require All Granted` は Apache httpd 2.4 向けの記述方法ですから 2.2 でうまく動くんでしたっけ？（記憶の彼方）とりあえず `apachectl -t` で httpd.conf の妥当性チェックしてみてください。 OK にならないなら conf は全面見直しになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問主ですがディレクトリの違いが問題では無かったようです。
再度質問させて頂きます。

Comment: 続きの質問はこちらのようです: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44836/19110