# top.phpがapacheに処理されない

Tags: php, centos, apache

apache2.4
php5.3.29
centos7

何時もお世話になっております。
質問事項は以下です

- top.phpが認識されない

/var/www/html/xxx/index.php
/var/www/html/xxx/lists.php 等
はphpファイルとして処理されるのですが

/var/www/html/xxx/top.php
だけがphpファイルとして処理されません。
ファイルを開くか保存するかの選択を迫られます。

top.phpの中身

```
<?php
phpinfo();
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'userAuth.php';
display('systemtop.tpl.php');
?>
```

apachectl -tにシンタックスエラーは出ていません。

そこで以下のことを試しました。

- top.phpをtop1.phpに変更

再度 localhost/XXX/top.phpにアクセスすると
上記のtop.phpを開く／保存を迫られました。
top.phpは存在しないはずなのに、どういうことでしょうか？

- top.phpの中身を変更を試みました

top.phpの中身

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

に変更し、localhost/XXX/top.phpにアクセスすると
再度、開く／保存を迫られ、開いてみると

```
<?php
phpinfo();
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'userAuth.php';
display('systemtop.tpl.php');
?>
```

がダウンロードされました。

キャッシュか何かが残っている？のでしょうか？

アドバイス／ご指摘／おしかり／何でもお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

質問主ですが
ブラウザにキャッシュがのこっていたことが原因でした。
キャッシュのクリアで解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

同一ディレクトリに配置しているphpファイルのうちtop.phpだけが静的ファイルとして扱われるということでしょうか？
ls -l *.php してみて、パーミッションに問題がないか（apache実行ユーザおそらく「apache」に実行権が存在するかなど確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？
あとは、apacheのアクセスログを確認するとか。。べたなアドバイスでごめんなさい。

Comment: ブラウザにキャッシュが残っていいたため、過去のtop.phpが表示されていたようでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: なるほど。了解しました。わざわざのコメントありがとうございます。